# Zodiac program, with Comparing int.input to variables with incrementle Ranges

Tags: python, variables, range

So I'm trying to write a program in Python that asks the user to input their birthday in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format and than have them confirm their birthday by comparing the `mm` entered to a list of the 12 months and then display something like "so you were born on (month=mm), (dd), of (year=YYYY).  I'm not quite sure how to compare the int.input to the (month,month,month)=range 1-13 to import the variable month into a print string.

But the major issue is comparing the input year to the extensive range of possibilities

```
rat  range (1901, 2020, 12)
ox  range (1902, 2020, 12)
tiger  range (1903, 2020, 12)
rabbit range (1904, 2020, 12)
dragon  range (1905, 2020, 12)
snake  range (1906, 2020, 12)
horse  range (1907, 2020, 12)
goat  range (1908, 2020, 12)
monkey  range (1909, 2020, 12)
rooster  range (1910, 2020, 12) 
dog  range (1911, 2020, 12)
pig  range (1912, 2020, 12)
```

I know I could set each date on its own but that's at least 100 different variables or `if` statements. is there a way to either set a numeric variable the has increments, such as
`A = 1901 + 12 (continued)` so if any year is = to 1901 or any number in the series such as 1913 or 1937, or a way to set a ranged variable that can be equated to the int that the user input?

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the user his birthday `answer = raw_input()`, check if the conversion to a date is valid using try and except:

```
from datetime import datetime
while true:
   print 'Input date (DD/MM/YYYY)'
   answer = raw_input()
   try:
      date = datetime.strptime(answer, '%d/%m/%Y')
      print 'So you were born in {}'.format(date.month)
      break
   except:
      pass
```

Comment: Is this what u wanted?